# update_attributes does not update nested_attributes in some cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, update-attributes

I am writing a little CMS application with rails 3.2.8. There is a model for paragraphs (basically holding the title, body and date of e.g. a news article) and for pages (consisting of many paragraphs, e.g. many news articles). The following does update a paragraph only, if the date changed, otherwise, the paragraph does not get updated, even if e.g. the body changed!?

```
page.update_attributes({"paragraphs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"0", 
             "title"=>"News title", "body"=>"News text", "id"=>"4", 
             "date(3i)"=>"1", "date(2i)"=>"1", "date(1i)"=>"2013"}}})
```

Below, you can find the relevant part of the models:

page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :paragraphs, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :name, :paragraphs_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paragraphs, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

paragraph.rb

```
class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :page, :date
  validates :page,  presence: true
end
```

Does anybody have any idea about the reason for this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There is of course the possibility of a dirty workaround: Insert a fake update before the final update. Please note, that this is very bad style and doubles the database access for the update, but since I could not find another solution, I came up with the following solution:

page_controller.rb

```
class PageController < ApplicationController

  def update

    # Hack: Updating paragraphs fails for some strange reasons if their date 
    # did not change. Updating paragraphs with date changes works as expected.
    # To allow updates in all cases, we first make an update to an impossible
    # date and then make an update to the real date.


    # Define a year, that will never occure in the params.
    # This date will be used for the fake update.
    impossible_year = "1999"

    # Setup the fake params for the first fake update (Change the date fields of 
    # all paragraphs to an impossible date).
    fake_params = params[:page].deep_dup
    par_attrs = fake_params[:paragraphs_attributes]
    par_attrs.keys.each do |key|
      par_attrs[key]["date(1i)"] = impossible_year
    end

    # Perform the fake update.
    @page.update_attributes(fake_params)

    # Finally do the real update with the original params.
    @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d32965399ccfa2052a4d52b70db1bae0ca16830b/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L72

Check the syntax

```
   # Now, when you add the <tt>_delete</tt> key to the attributes hash, with a
    # value that evaluates to +true+, you will destroy the associated model:
    #
    #   member.avatar_attributes = { :id => '2', :_delete => '1' }
    #   member.avatar.marked_for_destruction? # => true
    #   member.save
    #   member.avatar #=> nil
```